# How to prevent svg on top of other div of triggering mouseleave

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mouseleave

I have an issue with `mouseleave`. (React/Typescript/CSS/HTML project).

**Situation**

(see picture at the bottom)

I got two `div` elements

```html
<>
   <div id="main">
   <div>
   <div id="onHover" style={{display: "none"}}>
   </div>
</>
```

and I got an `svg` on top of `div main`.

```tsx
return(
<svg className="click-through" pointer-events="none" width={1560} height={262}>
     <VictoryChart
         style={{
             parent: { pointerEvents: 'none' }
         }}
     >
        <VictoryArea
            style={{
                parent: { border: '1px solid #ccc', pointerEvents: 'none' }
            }}
        />
     </VictoryChart>
</svg>
)
```

Goal:

- Upon hovering over `div main`, `div onHover` should be displayed next to `div main`
- Upon leaving `div main`, `div onHover` should disappear again.

The first goal is no issue, the second one is: **Because of the `svg`, `mouseleave` is triggered too early.**

The whole situation as a picture (The dotted white lines are from the `svg` which trigger `mouseleave`, the blue box would be `div main`):

[image]

For other reasons, the `svg` can't go behind `div main`.
How can I make sure now that `svg` lines don't trigger `mouseleave`?

*Further Information*

- For the `svg` I'm using `victory js` to display graphs
- That `svg` has the property `click through` and `pointer-events: none`
- This situation is heavily simplified but explains my key problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add `pointer-events: none;` to that SVG? Here is an example (green box does not fire any event but the blue one does):

```js
const wrap = document.querySelector('.mouseleave');
wrap.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  console.log(".mouseleave left");
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.mouseleave {
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.p-none, .p-default {
  height: calc(100% - 2rem);
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
}
.p-none {
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 2px solid green;
  left: 1rem;
}
.p-default {
  border: 2px solid cyan;
  right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="mouseleave"></div>
  <div class="p-none">pointer events: none</div>
  <div class="p-default">pointer events: default</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do have that property in my `svg` - unfortunately, same issue. As suggested from @zergski, I'll try `PointerEvent` instead `MouseEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

the `pointer-events: none` property needs to be set in css

but the more modern(and very performant) way is to use a PointerEvent instead of MouseEvent and bind the event to the desired element.. that way all other element listeners dont fire at all..

```
element.setPointerCapture(ev.pointerId)
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to the `svg` in regards of using css? I thought `svg` supports that property, neverthless I tried it with css and still same issue. However, I'll try `PointerEvent` and get back to you when I know more.

Comment: what does you styles inspector in dev tools say? is the pointer-events property applied? if inline, does it show up as markup attribute? if you add that property in dev tools, does it behave correctly.. etc

Comment: It's applied indeed but has apparently no effect. When I'm in the blue box everything is fine (onmouseenter is triggered) but as soon as I cross one of the white-dotted-lines onmouseleave is triggered. You can say with 100% certainty that `pointer-events: none` on the `svg` should prevent this behaviour? If yes, I'll continue trying to figure out why that's not the case.

Comment: You're right, I found a `svg` part that does not inherit my set property but has its own definition of `pointer-events: painted`. Switching that to `none` in dev tool fixed the issue. Do you know by any chance how I can override that, without having access to that `svg` part in Code? (it's hidden in an external React component)

Comment: I think I managed something with wrapper '<g>' elements..